# How to connect to a remote SQL Server (currently accessed via Citrix Netscaler) from local?

Tags: sql-server, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

I am connecting to a remote SQL Server from a system. This system is also remote, meaning I am connecting to it via Citrix Netscaler. That is, there is no VPN or anything. This looks like kind of RDP for me and is painfully slow. Is there a way to connect to via my local SQL Developer?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You didn't add the OS you are working on, but you should look into ssh tunneling if you are working on a *NIX box, or are using Putty. You can then set up the connections from you local machine to forward to the remote box, and it will be as if you are connecting on your local machine. This should minimize your transmission to just the data you are trying to send and receive.

Comment: I wonder ,if no VPN, how it could be possible ?

Comment: Looks like Citrix Netscaler is web delivery only so I'm guessing no. You'd need to get the network people to open a port (usually 1433) in order to connect directly with SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Developer is usually for Oracle - is that what you're using?)

Comment: I am using Windows 10. I do have a Linux box which I use for other purposes via SSH.